# Activity in android studio don´t show nothing, but also retun error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i´m developping one app with Android in Android Studio and Kotlin. I my MainActivity that this have two button.

1 button: call to activity 2, that it have 5 button for to do operation with database.
2 button: call to other activity that it have other button to call one new service that play, stop and pause one video.

In my activity 2, when i call since main activity... I go to this ok, but activity don´t show any button... but nevertheless show alert that i put there for notify me in which activity i´m.

I have to tell that i´m starting in android, kotlin, android studio... Sorry for attach very much code, but i don´t know what code attach, for this i attach, mainActivity XML, activity 2.xml and activity 2.kt

Thanks so much for help me

**MAIN**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="PAC Desarrollo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
        android:text="Ir a Activity 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        android:text="Ir a Acrtivity 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ACTIVITY2.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PracticaDesarrollo.AppBarOverlay"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="419dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.PracticaDesarrollo.PopupOverlay" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCrear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crear Tabla"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btInsertar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insertar Datos"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="209dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btConsultar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar Datos"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="45dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btVolver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Volver"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity2.kt**

```
package com.example.practicadesarrollo
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btCrear: Button
    private lateinit var btInsertar: Button
    private lateinit var btConsultar: Button
    private lateinit var btVolver: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        btCrear = findViewById(R.id.btCrear)
        btInsertar = findViewById(R.id.btInsertar)
        btConsultar = findViewById(R.id.btConsultar)
        btVolver = findViewById(R.id.btVolver)



        /*findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }*/


        btCrear.setOnClickListener({
            val intent = Intent(this, CrearTabla::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btInsertar.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, InsertarDatos::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btConsultar.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, ConsultarDatos::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btVolver.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        this.showAlertDialog()

    }


    private fun showAlertDialog() {
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity2)
        alertDialog.setTitle("")
        alertDialog.setMessage("Usted está en la activity 2")
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(
                "yes"
        ) { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this@Activity2, "Alert Cerrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(
                "No"
        ) { _, _ -> }
        val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

too i have to say that i have code comment  in activity2.kt this is why if i don´t comment this, my app close unexpectedly. How i said i i´m noob in Android, kotlin, etc... I´m searching help in google, and here for to can learn more

Thanks so much and sorry for my english and so much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my question. I don´t have a layout for create components. I created one and now all run ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
```

this is giving null because you don't have a floating button with id "fab" in activity2.xml and probably not in layout content_3.xml.you must be getting null pointer exception.

Comment: ok, @Rishabh Ritweek i show it better. But wich should be my problem with when i go to activity 2 i can´t show any button?. Really i don´t have a FloatingActionButton but i have other and i can´t show it...